# Subspaces of a Vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following are true for subspaces $U, U_1$ and $U_2$ of a vector space $V$ and why:

(a) $U=-U$ with $-U=\{-v|v\in U\}$

(b) $U+U \subset U$

(c) $U+(-U)=\{0\}$

(d) $U_1+U_2+(-U_2)=U_1$

My idea:

(a) TRUE because I cannot make U larger by giving vector from $U$ to it. In Fact should it be $U+U=U$ or more general $nU=U$ for $n\in \mathbb{R}$?

(b) TRUE because of scalar product of all vectors in $U$ (also for $-1$) is in $U$.

(c) FALSE i.e. $a\neq b$, $a,b \in U: a-b \neq \{0\}$

(d) FALSE Same as (c)

Comment: your right. But for $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: If $V$ is a *real* vector space, then the linear map $U\rightarrow U$ given by $u\mapsto n u$ is bijective for $n\neq 0$. If $U$ is a vector space over, say, $\mathbb{Q}$, then $nu$ is not defined for irrational $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. If $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then we know that it is closed with respect to vector addition and scalar multiplication. Since $U$ is closed, it follows that if $-v \in U$, then $(-1)(-v) = v \in U$. As you suggested, this holds for any non-zero scalar. Similarly, if we take $U_1+U_2$ to mean the sum of each element in $U_1$ with each element in $U_2$, then $U+U=U$ because of closure. After you realize this, the rest of the problems follow as you indicated.